# Values updating on debug but not on runtime

Tags: c#, debugging, c#-4.0, runtime, updates

I have a weird problem to explain here. I have a wizard with multiple screens. In my first screen I am reading an XML file and its been read and its values shown/used for screens. In one of the screen, I am changing these values and then hit `Update` button to update the data. But at the end of the wizard, when I click finish the changed values are not saved properly. I have confirmed this with code as well that the changed values were not present while exporting the data.

But the real kick came when I started debugging. Till now I was debugging only when the data is being exported. But then I started debugging from start of the wizard. I noticed while debugging that, when I hit `Update` button after changing values, this time the values were updated and correct data was exported. But when I run the application in runtime or put a debug point directly at export process, the changed data is not reflected.

So the problem is, when I debug the changed values are being exported and in runtime it do not. Can anyone suggest me something on this?

However I noticed later that sometimes in runtime its updating and sometimes not. But it gets always updated when I debug. If it matters, I am using Winforms and MVP.

**EDIT**

I must also admit that when I put `Thread.Sleep(2000)` at the end of `Update` button event method, everything looks good and works fine. But however this way is not being appreciated by my code reviewers and either this method is not pleasing me.

**Edit Again**

The `Update` button uses the main thread and updates the value in the same thread. However, when I click finish, its creating a `BackgroundWorker` and running a `ExportData` method from there. I cannot see any more threads there with my present observation and knowledge.

Comment: Do you have multiple threads?

Comment: I was afraid of being asked this question. I need to write many more lines now :):). Please see edit :)

Comment: Could you add a "Hi" popup at the very end of the `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork` method, to make sure that it finishes execution? Also, try running it synchronously just to see if the problem is here or someplace before in code.

Comment: "Hi" popup stuff worked fine.

Comment: Have you tried running it synchronously?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response.....It works great in synchronous call....so, now what?

Comment: Post the relevant code